# CSS on meta tags

Tags: css, meta-tags

I want to use capital case on a meta tag property that goes to Facebook.

I.e.:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="this is the great title to a post" />
```

EDIT:

I tried:

```
.property og:title {
 text-transform: capitalize:
}
```

This did not work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why? They're not rendered in the browser.

Comment: Facebook is merely reading it as a string. There is no style information to go with it. So the answer is: you can't.

Comment: _"How can I do that?"_ **You can't**

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started.

```
function capitalize(myString) {
  var myString = myString.split(" ");
  var capitalized = [];
  for(each in myString) {
    capitalized.push(
      myString[each][0].toUpperCase() +
      myString[each].substring(1).toLowerCase()
    );
  }
  return capitalized.join(" ");
}

$("[property='og:title']").attr({"content": capitalize("whatever you wanna capitalize")});
```

Haven't tested the jquery, but at least the function works.